# Node.js Can you trigger a clickevent on a different page?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

So i want to get a link which is stored in a website. The website I want to get the link from is https://skribbl.io. If you click on the create "**Create Private Room"**-button the site refreshes and shows the link to share (which i want to get). If you are on the landing page you have to trigger a click Event on the **"Create Private Room"** button. Can i even do this and if yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably get this done on nodejs using a package called "Cheerio" its basically server-side Jquery library.

So you would run a request on the page from node and then parse the response using Cheerio to extract the text.

If the page you want to webscrape requires you to perform clicks then you might want to consider looking at a library package called NightmareJS which can perform headless page automation via scripts that you write.